# Fontawesome 4.3 Installation

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have downloaded Fontawesome pack (including css, Less and other supporting files) and copied the files to my website

I am using Gantry framework. It says to edit Head Section to add custom code.

I need help in two things,

1. How to edit the head tag
2. How to enter the `fontawesome.css` file to my page so it starts showing icons on my page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what it is telling you to do is to:

1. add the link to the stylesheet in the head tag of you website. For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/FILEPATH/fontawesome.css">`
2. In your html, you would just add icons by adding an empty tag (usually a span or i tag) where you want an icon. For example: `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>`

Comment: Thanks Sean for Replying, my question is still there. how can i edit Head tag, or in which file i need to edit, do i have to edit index.php file or any other.. Please dont mind I am new to joomla environment.

Comment: I have no experience with joomla, but usually there is a file called header.php or something along those lines. In that file, you should see a link tag to at least one css file. You can add the font awesome link below that.

Comment: you need to put your css file in joomla installation templates/system/css folder than open index.php of the current active template from templates/{active template name}/index.php and put your code like this  before </head>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $document->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/fontawesome.css" />

Comment: i put these codes, its still not working. infact i m now getting 500 Internal server error ..

<?php (link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/gantry/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")  ?>
and the second one which you mentioned earlier. i am getting the same error